# Any issues with disabling local DNS Cache on Ubuntu Server 18.04 or 20.04 or 22.04

Tags: dns, cache

My Ubuntu 18.04 server is used to create websites and initiate SSL's via an Admin panel. The issue is that when I initiate the SSL I like to have the server check the DNS record, but since the client just changed the record on their Registrar the DNS hasn't propagated to my server yet. This is not a big deal as instead I now just ping 'https://dns.google.com/resolve' to get that info as it seems to not retain any cache as long.

However, another issue is that my server also checks the websites uptime, but since the client just changed the record on their Registrar the DNS hasn't propagated to my server yet. So then I can just ping the domain until it has propagated.

A manual solution is for me to just login and run `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` but I obviously don't want to do that all the time.

So can I just run a cronjob to clear the dns cache every minute or 5 minutes?
Or maybe just disable DNS Cache all together?

What kind of issues will I run into doing either one of these?
What are the main disadvantages will I get with either one of these?

I am assuming my uptime checks, which are run every 5 minutes, will take slightly longer now, but I am assuming that is just milliseconds.

What type of issues will I have with apt, ntp, or other internal systems if I do one of these?

Thanks